Using re to match a digit + any contiguous duplicates and storing the duplicates, not just the digit as the result
I'm trying to use re.findall(pattern, string) to match all numbers and however many duplicates follow in a string. Eg. "1222344" matches "1", "222", "3", "44". I can't seem to find a pattern to do so though.
I tried using the pattern "(\d)\1+" to match a digit 1 or more times but it doesn't seem to be working. But when I print the result, it shows up as an empty array [].

Well, you say you know the code works as the 12345 example works. however your first regex isn't the same pattern. It say (and I quote from regex101.com) \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy). So it will only match the 222 and 44 since they are only ones where a digit is duplicated (or more) successively.


I used the fact that I could match at all just as an example that I was in fact matching stuff, and it wasn't my literal code that was the issue, though it probably wasn't worth mentioning. The initial pattern I mentioned was one that I found through other resources that didn't match the single digits and their succeeding duplicates.

You can use itertools.groupby for this. groups = [''.join(group) for _, group in groupby(yourIterable)]. It's probably faster than regex and you can do the job all on one line

You're on the right track but your pattern (\d)\1+ actually matches two or more contiguous digits (the first digit is matched by \d and then the + quantifier says match one or more of that digit.  So what you want is (\d)\1* where the * says match zero or more of that previous digit
The other thing that is perhaps confusing is that re.findall() only returns a list of the matched subexpressions (in this case the individual digit) to see the entire string matched you can use re.search() or re.finditer() to get a match object then access the entire matched string using mo.group(0)
import re
text = "122333444455555666666"

patt = re.compile(r"(\d)\1*")

print()
print(patt.findall(text))       # print list of JUST first digit in each run

print()
for mo in patt.finditer(text):  # iterate over all the Match Objects 
    print(mo.group(0))          # group(0) is the entire matched string

Output is:
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']  

1
22
333
4444
55555
666666


I appreciate it. It did work out, but I'm still curious. Is there a way to match all duplicates with a function like findall and have them stored? Like pattern.findall( "122333") would store ["1", "22", 333"] in an array? Or can I only access the duplicates by iterating through match objects.

Could do: `def find_repeats(s:str)->list:
patt = re.compile(r"(\d)\1*")
return [mo.group(0) for mo in patt.finditer(s)]
find_repeats("122333")`

@Ethan "re.findall returns captured texts if the regex pattern contains capturing groups in it", so it is best to use re.finditer. You can create a workaround by wrapping the full pattern with another capturing group while adjusting the backreference number, and then get the first item from each tuple in the output list, but it is really ugly and you will still need a list comprehension.

@Ethan - yeah as @Wiktor says, once you have at least one subexpression in your regular expression then re.findall() only returns the subexpressions as a tuple:  So if you adjust the RE to be this patt = re.compile(r"((\d)\2*)")  then the results of  patt.findall(text) would be [('1', '1'), ('22', '2'), ('333', '3'), ('4444', '4'), ('55555', '5'), ('666666', '6')] then, as suggested, you could use a list comprehension to extract the first item of each tuple: [t[0] for t in patt.findall(text)] which is just another variation of the suggestion from @Duesser
